# LVDS is not a full-pin connector?

Tags: computer-building, display-adapter, soldering

Rather than SubD a LVDS can have different sizes because the adapter I bought is too big.

[image]

Before I cut the cables and melt sinker and solder them directly, I have to ask a question:

[image]

There is a gap before the last 3 pins of the supplier cable (bottom) I can not find in the according pins of the LVDS male plug.

[image]

Are they dead, ground or shall I connect further pins?
[image]